# how to use ajax trigger php function that store values in array

Tags: php, mysql, ajax

I am using a Mysql table and php, to print some data on a page with a button next to each data value. When the button is clicked for each value (with unique id), an ajax call is made to trigger a php function that inserts the button id in an array.

The problem is, when I click one of the buttons, the values are inserted inside the array, however when another button is clicked, the existing values in the array are deleted and only the new values are there.

I am not sure what I could do to stop existing values to stay in the array.

Here is my Code for the function **phpfile.php**

```
 public function storing_value(){

     $qry= $_GET['passedvalue'];


     $info = array();
     $info[$qry]= $qry;

     foreach($info as $key => $value)
        {

          echo $value;

        }
 }
```

**index page**

```
    <script> <!---------- A J A X  PART --- no need to worry about this---->
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str == "") {
            document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = "";
            return;
        } else { 
            if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
                // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } else {
                // code for IE6, IE5
                xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML = this.responseText;
                }
            };
            xmlhttp.open("GET","phpfile.php?passedvalue="+str,true);
            xmlhttp.send();
        }
    }
</script>  <!---------- A J A X  PART --- no need to worry about this---->

<div id="txtHint">
<b>All array data will be printed here every time button is clicked</b>

</div>

<?php foreach($values as $value) {?> 

<button class="<?= $value['id']; ?>"     
        value="<?= $value['id']; ?>"  
        onclick="showUser(this.value)" >Like</button>

<?php } ?>
```

So every time the function is called, the pre-existing array values get deleted.

Thanks in advance

Comment: `$info[$qry]= $qry;` means you always have array with ONE element with index $qry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your file first line start session and use one session variable to store your array values like below

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
```

and modified your code like below to use session

```
public function storing_value(){
     $qry= $_GET['passedvalue'];
     $_SESSION['myarray'][$qry]= $qry;

     foreach($_SESSION['myarray'] as $key => $value)
        {
          echo $value;
        }
 }
```

Comment: wow very nice thanks alot @Mahipal Patel. Does the array values get reset everytime with my method? I thought the arrays store for each key until you destroy it